Extension keep vanishing in Sagemaker VS Code Editor
I'm using VS Code Editor in Sagemaker Studio, and I've installed a Snowflake extension. The VS Code Editor space is automatically stopped by out org IT team every night. When I restart the space, the extension is gone. However, if I install it back, it retains all the information I entered earlier (e.g. account identifier for snowflake). Is it possible to keep the extension consistent i.e. prevent it from uninstalling? Or if I could automatically re-install extension when I restart the space?
I don't have any access to the Sagemaker Studio itself apart from creating and accessing the space. The IT team controls all of the other aspects.
I installed an extension and I was expecting it to remain installed over sessions

By default, Code Editor extensions appear to be installed into a folder in the Sagemaker Studio docker image (which does not persist between sessions) rather than persistent storage in your space.  Looking at the entrypoint configuration in the Sagemaker distribution image, Code Editor is started with an argument to store extensions in /opt/amazon/sagemaker/sagemaker-code-editor-server-data/extensions which likely doesn't outlive the container instance.
You need to override this argument one way or another—--I have had success with custom images (that I would use anyway for other dependencies) with Docker CMD arguments to set the extension directory to inside /home/sagemaker-user so they are written to my space.  For instance, this image sample from Amazon could use the --extensions-dir argument:
CMD eval "$(micromamba shell hook --shell=bash)"; \
    micromamba activate base; \
    sagemaker-code-editor --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8888 \
        --without-connection-token \
        --base-path "/CodeEditor/default" \
        --extensions-dir "/home/rstudio/"

It may be possible to do something similar through a lifecycle script setting an environment variable that VSCode uses, but I haven't been able to make that work.  (I suspect it wouldn't override the argument Amazon put in the Docker image).
